Access pixel counts in ee.Reducer.histogram
I have a cloud mask raster in Google Earth Engine that consists of pixels with values 0 (= cloud) and 1 (= not cloud) and want to count the number of cloud pixels in order to only export images with less than a certain percentage of cloud coverage.
Using ee.reduceRegion(), I am able to create an object that includes the information I am looking for, but I can't seem to figure out how to extract the pixel counts in a way that could be used in an if-statement later on. This is my code:
var count = mask_raster.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.histogram(),
  geometry: geometry,
  scale: 30,
  maxPixels: 1e9
})

print(count);

The output in the console looks like this:

Now I would like to simply get the number of pixels under the histogram property in a format that could be used in a statement along the lines of:
if pixel_count_0 < 5000:
    Export.image.toDrive({
       ...
       })
else:
    pass

I am pretty new to Earth Engine, and usually code in Python, so I am a bit confused about how ee.Objects work. I tried to convert count into a string or list or access the data the way I would access a dictionary in Python using a key, but nothing seems to work - am I thinking about variables in Earth Engine incorrectly?
